# How to enable location in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, location, settings, android-jetpack-compose

I am requesting location permissions and even after the user granted location permissions i cannot get gps location if location settings is disabled. How can i request user to enable the location settings in jetpack compose?

```
   val multiplePermissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
        listOf(
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        )
    )
 
 Button(onClick = {
                    multiplePermissionsState.launchMultiplePermissionRequest()
                },
                modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
            )
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create enable location permission dialog like google map.

```
import android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK
import android.content.Context
import android.content.IntentSender
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.compose.rememberLauncherForActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.IntentSenderRequest
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException
import com.google.android.gms.location.*
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
```

```
@Composable
fun Layout() {

    val context: Context = LocalContext.current
    
    val settingResultRequest = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ) { activityResult ->
        if (activityResult.resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            Log.d("appDebug", "Accepted")
        else {
            Log.d("appDebug", "Denied")
        }
    }

    Button(onClick = {
        checkLocationSetting(
            context = context,
            onDisabled = { intentSenderRequest ->
                settingResultRequest.launch(intentSenderRequest)
            },
            onEnabled = { /* This will call when setting is already enabled */ }
        )
    }) {
        Text(text = "Request permission")
    }

}


// call this function on button click
fun checkLocationSetting(
    context: Context,
    onDisabled: (IntentSenderRequest) -> Unit,
    onEnabled: () -> Unit
) {

    val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
        interval = 1000
        fastestInterval = 1000
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    }

    val client: SettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context)
    val builder: LocationSettingsRequest.Builder = LocationSettingsRequest
        .Builder()
        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
    
    val gpsSettingTask: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> =
        client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
    
    gpsSettingTask.addOnSuccessListener { onEnabled() }
    gpsSettingTask.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        if (exception is ResolvableApiException) {
            try {
                val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest
                    .Builder(exception.resolution)
                    .build()
                onDisabled(intentSenderRequest)
            } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                // ignore here
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: great!... but how to call this from a button click... when i try this ... it gives me the error that  in rememberLauncherForActivityResult '@Composable invocation should happen inside the @Composable function'... Please help me on this

Comment: @Venkataramanan I updated the answer hope it will help you. Happy coding!

Comment: @KunalSharma  Would you mind to share full code snippet including imports? Because your solution does not work for me. (any response is highly appreciated)

Comment: If i call checkLocationSetting in Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME, it sometimes show error: "You must ensure the ActivityResultLauncher is registered before calling launch()."

Answer (score 2):

You could use Google's Accompanist library:
(https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/)

Since their website contains example code, I'll not paste the code here.

Comment: the link you provide is only for handling permissions and not enabling GPG settings location as he asked